Cases where a misunderstanding in mathematics led to misunderstanding of the physics?
Originally, I asked this question on Physics SE, but it was immediately suggested that I ask this question here. Quite soon afterwards, the question was closed on (see below).
Quite some time ago, Anthony Zee, professor in theoretical physics at the Kavli Institute for Theoretical Physics (KITP) asked the following question during a coffee break. Namely, are there any cases where misunderstanding the mathematics led to a misunderstanding the physics? I came up with one example, concerning the Schwarzschild metric. Before the Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates were discovered, the nature of the horizon was not properly understood. From the Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates, it is clear that one can cross the horizon, without noticing anything special, at least at first.
Are there any other examples where a misunderstanding of the mathematics led to a misunderstanding of the physics?
One of the criticisms this question got on Physics SE was that the question was not focussed enough. More in particular, it was argued that it's not clear what is considered a 'misunderstanding of the mathematics' and what a 'misunderstanding of the physics'. So, let me try to clarify this a bit. With a misunderstanding of the mathematics, I'm thinking of a more fundamental problem, rather than a simple miscalculation, sign error et cetera. In the example above, the problem was that a coordinate singularity was not properly identified as such. This then led to a wrong conclusion about the physics (one can not cross the horizon).

Well, of course, your example of the nature of the horizon is mathematics, not physics. No experimental evidence of the nature of the horizon will ever be published unless the theory is wrong.

I don't know if this counts; What exactly was Lagrange's "grave mistake" with respect to rotating bodies under hydrostatic equilibrium?

@uhoh I didn't go through all the details of the Maclaurin spheroid and Jacobi ellipsoid, but it certainly seems to be a nice example of what I was looking for.

Newton in Principia calculated the rotation of the line of lunar apsides which accounted for only about half of the observed motion, and then fudged the numbers to get the correct prediction, see Chandler, The Principia's theory of the motion of the lunar apse. But when his calculations were re-examined by Clairaut in 1740-s the discrepancy came out.
Clairaut reduced the problem to solving a system of four differential equations and approximated the solution using Newton's ansatz for the Moon's radius-vector. The observed motion appeared inconsistent with the inverse square law, so much so that Clairaut proposed corrections to it involving inverse cube term in 1747. The ensuing drama involved Euler and d’Alembert, among others, criticizing Clairaut's corrections, and is described in Bodenmann, The 18th-century battle over lunar motion. D’Alembert instead postulated an additional  magnetic force and Euler was looking for better gravity corrections. Berlin Academy prize of 1750 for establishing whether "every inequality that we observe in the motion of the Moon accord with the Newtonian Theory" was at stake.
Long story short, 2 years later Clairaut announced that the motion of the apsides did follow the inverse square law after all, no corrections required. The problem was with Newton's ansatz that led to neglecting significant terms in the perturbative approximation to the solution (that Clairaut did not announce and kept to himself until 1750). Mathematical details are reviewed in Cook's Success and failure in Newton's lunar theory:

"Clairaut had assumed that the orbit of the
Moon would have the polar equation... of an ellipse referred to axes rotating at the rate
$(1-c)$; $c$ is a constant to be determined from
the analysis. That is equivalent to Newton's
assumption. When he substituted that expression in an equation for the time as a function of true longitude, Clairaut, not surprisingly, obtained the same result as Newton. He realized that he
should take a better approximation for the
radius vector... He then found a satisfactory result for the rotation of the apse line. 
The reasons for Newton’s failure will now be
clear. Clairaut’s solution for the rotating curve is not an ellipse in a fixed frame – instead of a single periodic term, the reciprocal radius, referred to fixed axes, has an infinite number of incommensurable periodic components and is not a
closed curve. By constraining the rotating orbit
to be of the same form as the fixed one, Newton
imposed a condition inconsistent with the
dynamics – it can only be satisfied with an
inverse-cube force.  [...] Evidently the motion of perigee cannot be found
independently of a complete integration of the
equations of motion for the perturbed orbit, in
contrast to the theory of the node which is to
first order independent of the form of a nearly
circular orbit. Expressions for the perturbations
of the orbit, of the eccentricity and the rotation
of the apse line, can be derived geometrically,
but the integration would again involve coupled
equations and is not straightforward."


That's an interesting story story and along the lines I was thinking about!

Maybe an evident one, Maxwell's equations led to a wave equation with speed $c$ (equal to the speed of light). It was to be interpreted like any other wave equation, that is $c$ is the speed relative to the frame of reference where the medium is still. That medium was called the aether, however for the case of electromagnetism there was no such a thing as later explained both by experiments and by Lorentz invariance and special relativity.
An exemplary case seems to be the ergodic hypothesis. If you make many random iterations of a system, the ensemble average is equal to the long time average (equally distributed energy, thermalization). However during the Fermi–Pasta–Ulam–Tsingou experiment of 1953,  one of the first times that ergodicity was tested with a computer, the hypothesis did not hold. The simulation was considered a trivial exercise and the result was not expected at all. The thing is that their problem was equivalent to Korteweg-De Vries equation, a non-linear equation which admits soliton solutions. Solitons do not disperse and impede the system from thermalizing. Funny enough, it was the same Martin Kruskal from the Kruskal–Szekeres coordinates that tied this problem to the KdV equation.

Interesting that they started testing with soliton solutions, and funny indeed that it was the same Kruskal helping sorting things out...

In which sense ist the first example a misunderstanding of the mathematics?

The second example is backwards: misunderstanding of the physics led to misunderstanding of the mathematics. Many physical systems exhibit rapid thermalization through couplings between degrees of freedom. It was supposed that this was a universal property. But it isn't, and real systems sometimes resist thermalization. "Thermodynamics doesn't work in plasmas." -- Bruno Coppi

@JohnDoty well the ergodic hypothesis is a mathematical statement, the problem is that its limitations were not clearly understood.

@MichaelBächtold well the mathematics were very clear, electromagnetism as a whole was invariant under Lorentz transformations, this was the real physics, people instead keep chasing the aether to explain its contradiction with Galilean invariance. Einstein just interpreted the mathematics correctly.

@Mauricio Didn't Lorentz transformations come later? I thought Lorentz originally came up with them in an attempt at preserving the aether, and they just turned out to be useful for relativity. Or am I thinking of something else Lorentz developed?

@Idran many people came up with Lorentz transformation before Einstein's paper on relativity. See history of Lorentz transformations. Yes Lorentz transformations were understood as dynamics of the aether.
